# How to choose what source of stream needs to be processed in Storm?

Tags: java, stream, rpc, apache-storm

I'm struggling with one thing in Storm.
So the whole idea is:

1. Send a request to the storm (probably to DRPC Server). The request will tell Storm what is the source of streams. For example: Image that I have two files `1 - '/var/log/syslog'` and `2- ' /var/log/udev`' . I want to be able to send the request to the "Storm" to tell it what file to process.

What I don't understand:

When I said send request to the "Storm", - Where should I send it? ( I assume that DRPC server controls what source needs to be send to topology. But how to implement DRPC server? Is there some class like `DRPCServer server = new DRPCServer()`? And how to tell Spout to look at the DRPCServer?Or is the request needs to be send directly to the `Spout`? if So how to make it start using specified source? I mean do I need to send request to the `open()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not DRPCServer, its DRPCClient

```
DRPCClient client = new DRPCClient("drpc-host", 3772);
```

I think you will be really interested after seeing [this](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Distributed-RPC)

**UPDATE:**
And for more information you can always check the storm-starter project in github by nathanmarz and especially [BasicDRPCTopology](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/BasicDRPCTopology.java)and [ReachTopology](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/ReachTopology.java)

Comment: I looked at this documentation, but still didn't get one thing: What is DRPC Server????? is it DRPCSpout? the example you gave, is it how you would connect to the Nimbus?

Comment: DRPC Server in nothing but the nimbus in drpc mode. For starting DRPC server you can use `./bin/storm drpc ` on your nimbus node

Comment: OMG Thank you very much you just opened my eyes!